# "Permission denied" error from gunicorn in docker container

Tags: docker, gunicorn

I get an error:
`sh: can't create /home/dev/app/logs/gunicorn.log: Permission denied`

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.11.5-alpine
RUN adduser -D dev
EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /home/dev/app
COPY requirements.txt /home/dev/app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /home/dev/app/requirements.txt
USER dev
COPY . /home/dev/app
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "gunicorn core.app:app -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 > /home/dev/app/logs/gunicorn.log 2>&1"]
```

I've already tried using chmod and mkdir, but I still get this error. I don’t even know how to fix this anymore. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error and run gunicorn as the "dev" user?

Answer (score 0):

You almost never want to log to a file in Docker.  A typical setup is to log to stdout instead.  Docker will collect the main container's stdout and stderr and you can review it with `docker logs`, or most open-source log collectors know how to read Docker's log storage.

If you remove the redirection at the end of your command then it won't try to write to a file, you'll be on the standard logging setup, and you won't have this permission problem.  I'd also suggest changing `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` to make it easier to debug the container and to support some setup-script use cases, and removing the shell wrapper since it's no longer necessary.

```bash
CMD ["gunicorn", "core.app:app", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

If you really want to keep the original form, you need to write the logs to a directory that's writable by the container user.  I'd suggest using a dedicated directory for this purpose; `chown` it to the non-root user before you switch away from being root.

```bash
COPY ./ ./
RUN mkdir logs \
 && chown dev logs
USER dev
CMD gunicorn core.app:app -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 >logs/gunicorn.log 2>&1
```

Again note that I've changed `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`, and I've let Docker insert the `sh -c` wrapper.

With this last setup, if you do need to read the logs from the host, you can bind-mount a host directory over the `logs` directory (only) and set the container to run as the host user with access to that directory.

```bash
docker run \
  -u $(id -u) \
  -v "$PWD/logs:/home/dev/app/logs" \
  ...
```